# HTML form data submitted to embedded mongodb

Tags: html, forms, mongodb

I want to insert data into a mongodb collection from a HTML Form and I want it to have a specific structure. e.g.

```
{name:{first_name:"", last_name:""}, address:{street:"",
post_code:""}}
```

In a normal form submission the data doesn't seem to have structure. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML cannot insert into MongoDB directly, you need an application layer, if your application is based on java, you can map the form values into an object of your choice and then save that object in MongoDB.

If you are using nodeJS, it is even easier where you can form the said structure on the frontend and make an ajax call to node server and it can save the passed request as it is into MongoDB.

If you must use HTML form, I think you will have to do the hard work of parsing the HTML data to object of desired structure.